# Not able to pass parameter from command line to maven project. I want to pass server url on which I can run my test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created Maven project for the first time and I was able to run it previously without passing parameter by using `mvn test` command. 
Now I want to pass parameter to it so i changes pom.xml but getting following error

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.209 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-23T12:52:44+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'exec' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 among available goals help, compile, testCompile -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException: Could not find goal 'exec' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 among available goals help, compile, testCompile
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.2.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.2.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-3.2.3.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Grok</groupId>
  <artifactId>MobileApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Login to app</name>
  <description>Login to Grok app</description>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>saucelabs-repository</id>
        <url>https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
     <artifactId>sauce_junit</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.3</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

   <build>
   <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Include Sauce Connect plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.saucelabs.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sauce-connect-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sauceUsername>admins-test-numenta</sauceUsername>
                    <sauceAccessKey>f6c91fa5-d400-42be-85e1-f7060098f922</sauceAccessKey>
                    <options>-i testing</options>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-sauceconnect</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-sauceconnect</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-sauceconnect</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop-sauceconnect</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec-one</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>echo</executable>
                            <variables>
                          <variable>serverUrl:${Gvars.server}</variable>
                        </variables>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                         <variables>
                              <variable>serverUrl:${RFvars.browser}</variable>
                            </variables>
                    </configuration>

                     <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            </execution>
                            </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins> 
           </pluginManagement> 
    </build>         
</project>
```

I am running this from command line

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:exec -DGvars.server=url_to_be_used
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in pom file or in command to run project.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your specified maven version is correct?

Comment: I think to define maven plugin way is : <plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
</plugin>             You have used something diff.

Comment: @HelpingHands Updated pom file with appropriate version

Comment: Is that working now?

Comment: @HelpingHands no still not working, same issue

Comment: @HelpingHands also tried  <plugin> 
             <inherited>true</inherited> 
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version> still issue is there

Comment: Getting same error or any change in error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) configuration. As the error message states the compiler plugin does not have an `exec` goal (`Could not find goal 'exec' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin`).

It only has two goals available and these are:

- `compile`
- `testCompile`

Also I'm not sure what you expect the compiler plugin to do with the `variables` configuration. It doesn't [know](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) about `variables` so will ignore it.

Change your compiler-plugin configuration to be as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>compile</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But actually this is the default configuration so you can simplify it even further to just be:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You realise that the compiler plugin is used to compile your local module's java source code, right? It is not going to understand an argument `serverUrl`. You can pass it compiler arguments (i.e. `-Xlint`) via the `compilerArgs` configuration of the plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

Comment: Additionally to execute the compiler plugin you would simply call `mvn compile`. You do not need to refer to it fully qualified as you have been trying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not updating my pom.xml

Just using `@Parameters({"url", "pwd"})` annotation of Testng

Its working for me.